Adding space between horizontal axis and horizontal bar bars
I am working on a simple bar chart, and I haven't been able to figure out how to add an extra space between the horizontal axis on top and the first horizontal graph ("Mines"). I would appreciate if anyone has an idea to solve this.
Here is my MWE:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.70\textwidth,
    height=0.60\textheight,
    xbar stacked,   
    xmin=0,         
    ytick=data,     
    symbolic y coords={Semi-fabricators, Refineries, Smelters, Mines},
    yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize, text=black}, 
    tickwidth=4pt,     
    axis x line*=top,
    xtick={0, 100, 200)},
    axis y line*=left,
    y axis line style={red,opacity=0},
    x axis line style={red,opacity=0},
    xticklabel style={font=\footnotesize, text=black},
    bar width=15pt, 
    y=1.25cm,        
]
   
\addplot [fill=copper6, draw=copper6, opacity=0.95] coordinates { 
    (206,Semi-fabricators)        
    (197,Refineries)
    (167,Smelters)
    (158,Mines)
  };
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}


@ Fernando could you make it runable?

"enlarge" the upper y limits.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.70\textwidth,
        height=0.60\textheight,
        xbar stacked,   
        xmin=0,         
        enlarge y limits={0.20,upper}, % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        clip=false, %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        ytick=data,     
        symbolic y coords={Semi-fabricators, Refineries, Smelters, Mines},
        yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize, text=black}, 
        tickwidth=4pt,     
        axis x line*=top,
        xtick={0, 100, 200)},
        axis y line*=left,
        y axis line style={red,opacity=0},
        x axis line style={red,opacity=0},
        xticklabel style={font=\footnotesize, text=black},
        bar width=15pt, 
        y=1.25cm,        
        ]
        
        \addplot [fill=red, draw=red, opacity=0.95] coordinates
         {(206,Semi-fabricators)        
            (197,Refineries)
            (167,Smelters)
            (158,Mines) };
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}

Or just use enlarge y limits={0.20}, to change both the upper and lower limits.

Thanks a lot! I wasn't aware of that command.
